# How can I combine filter values?

Tags: views, 9

I'm on D9.5.x.

I'm styling the default *Glossary* view. It works, but on the site some of the node titles start with a character that is not alphabetic, for example *- My awesome title -* or *@ My Work*. Therefore, the exposed title filter shows the alphabetic and non-alphabetic characters.

Instead of an option for each of the non-alphabetic characters, I would need to show a single option, for example *#*, for all the nodes with a title that starts with a non-alphabetic character.

How can I achieve this?